# Angular 2 - Unable to pass data into root component using ng-content and binding. Goal: Reuseable form component

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, razor, angular2-components

I have an existing .NET MVC application in which I would like to use Angular 2 in. I have a page similar to this (shorthand):

```
<html>
<head>css imports and jquery imports</head>
<body>
    <div>
        a bunch of tables existing in the HTML outputed by razor
    </div>
    <myForm postLocation='Management/User/Add'>
        <form #addForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitAddForm(addForm)">
            Username:
            <input ([ngModel])="user.username" type="text" required />
        </form>
    </myForm>
</body>
</html>
```

The gist is that I'm trying to make a reusable form component that has the form inputs passed in via ng-content. I pass in the post location so the http post knows where to post. The component looks like this:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'myForm',    
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
})

//The component that controls the datatable add form.
export class myForm {
    //Constructor
    constructor() {

    }

    //Properties
    @Input() postLocation: string;

    submitted = false;

    //Functions
    submitAddForm(form: NgForm) {
        console.log(form.value);
        console.log("Post Location: " + this.postLocation);
    }
}
```

When the page loads, the whole form disappears from the page. If I view source, I can still see the code in the html. No errors in the console.

If I instead bring my form and inputs into a separate cshtml file and make a controller action to pull it into the app via templateURL, I see the content on the page but post location is not filled in. It's undefined.

How can I get this to work? I want the myForm from to work with the existing html on the page that I'm passing in.

I had a mockup working in AngularJS. I am at a point where I'm redesigning the front end js framework for an application that will be used at least for another ten years. I feel like using angularjs now might be a poor decision if angular 2 is what is supported now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transclusion is currently not supported at the root component, but it is planned.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4946

Comment: Is there a timeline when? It seems like I should abandon angular 2 now but if I start the process with a different framework it will be harder to switch to angular in the future if need be.

Comment: I don't know about a timeline. Why does that HTML need to come from the outside?

Comment: I have items such as Resource files (.resx files) that I place strings in for localization and Model functions that get information. If I moved that into typescript, I couldn't be able to access the server side variables to fill in the strings and model data. Also this seems like you would need multiple components with just one string changed if they are all sharing similar functions.